How to create/use boost::multi_index with key types/values unrelated to the mapped type/value
I want a double-key "map" to access a type value.
The key types are unrelated to the mapped type.
Example:
  using key1_type   = double;
  using key2_type   = int;
  using mapped_type = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

Would like to use the boost::multi_index_container class for this.
How do I define such container. So I think the implementation starts like this:
using Container = 
boost::multi_index_container<
    mapped_type,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            ???
        >
        ,boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            ???
        >
    >
>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const mapped_type& e)
{
    os << e.first <<" " << e.second;
    return os;
}

And in main() how to:

Add elements to the container
Cout all elements in the container by either key1_type or key2_type
Get an element in the container by either the value of key1_type or key2_type

Many thanks

You need the equivalent of std::map's value_type, not just the mapped_type, e.g.
struct value_type {
    key1_type key1;
    key2_type key2;
    mapped_type data;
};

// Optional: Marker types to tag indexes
struct key1;
struct key2;

using Container = 
boost::multi_index_container<
    value_type,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<key1>,
            boost::multi_index::key<&value_type::key1>
        >
        ,boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<key2>,
            boost::multi_index::key<&value_type::key2>
        >
    >
>;

int main() {
    Container container;

Adding to a container:
    container.emplace(1.2, 3, { "some", "data" });
    container.emplace(2.4, 0, { "other", "data" });

Iterating by different keys:
    for (auto& [_, _, data] : container.get<key1>())
    {
        std::cout << data.first << data.second << "\n";
    }

Finding element by key:
    auto it = container.get<key2>().find(0);
}


Indeed the key concept here is, as you said, "You need the equivalent of std::map's value_type, not just the mapped_type"
The rest follows.
Thank you for putting time into answering.

The keys are not required to be members of the mapped type (albeit it makes it a bit easier if they are), as long as you have some way to obtain the key value given the mapped type.
You can use any of the Predefined key extractors (in your case global_fun would work), or write a user-defined key extractor to provide the function boost will use to create the index.
Example: godbolt

using key1_type   = double;
using key2_type   = int;
using mapped_type = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

key1_type key1_function(mapped_type const& mt) {
    // TODO map mapped_type to key1_type
    return std::stod(mt.first);
}

key2_type key2_function(mapped_type const& mt) {
    // TODO map mapped_type to key2_type
    return std::stoi(mt.second);
}

struct by_key1;
struct by_key2;

using Container = boost::multi_index_container<
    mapped_type,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<by_key1>,
            boost::multi_index::global_fun<
                mapped_type const&,
                key1_type,
                &key1_function
            >
        >,
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<by_key2>,
            boost::multi_index::global_fun<
                mapped_type const&,
                key2_type,
                &key2_function
            >
        >
    >
>;

To get access to the individual indices you can use .get() on a container instance (using either the
Container container;
// by index in the indexed_by definition
auto& key1_index = container.get<0>();
auto& key2_index = container.get<1>();

// using tags 
auto& key1_index = container.get<by_key1>();
auto& key2_index = container.get<by_key2>();


The indices then have the methods you are looking for to search specific elements using the index. (see Ordered Indices for a list of all available functions)
Example: godbolt
Container container;
container.emplace("1.023", "123");
container.emplace("3.455", "456");

auto& key1_index = container.get<by_key1>();
auto it = key1_index.find(1.023);
if(it != key1_index.end()) {
    std::cout << "found " << it->first << ", " << it->second << std::endl;
}
// will output "found 1.023, 123"


auto& key2_index = container.get<by_key2>();
auto it2 = key2_index.find(456);
if(it2 != key2_index.end()) {
    std::cout << "found " << it2->first << ", " << it2->second << std::endl;
}
// will output "found 3.455, 456"


You can count the elements having a specific value using .count() on the index.
Note though that you're using ordered_unique indices, so each key can only be present once.
So .count(x) will always return either 0 or 1.
If you want to allow duplicate values for key1_type / key2_type you would need to use another index type that allows duplicates (like e.g. ordered_non_unique)
Example: godbolt
Container container;
container.emplace("1.023", "123");
container.emplace("3.455", "456");

auto& key1_index = container.get<by_key1>();
// outputs 1
std::cout << "count 1.023: " << key1_index.count(1.023) << std::endl;
// outputs 0
std::cout << "count 9.999: " << key1_index.count(9.999) << std::endl;


The idea was that there can be any number of key types (2 or more) each of which has no conversion to the member types in the mapped_type. My bad that I did not not make that explicit.
Nevertheless there is a lot useful information here.
Thank you for putting time into answering.
